# How to use JOIN query here?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-db

I am using zend. I implemented Featured Products in Home page. Now I want to show the review under every product.Reviews may or may not be given for all products.I need to use query to fetch the products having review rating  and also not having the review rating.

Below is my code,

```
public function funFutureProduct($option = array())
{       
    $start = isset($option['start']) ? $option['start'] : 0;
    $limit = isset($option['limit']) ? $option['limit'] : Zend_Registry::get("featured_prod_row_length");
    $oDb=Zend_Registry::get("db");      
    $list_select = $oDb->select()
        ->from(array('p'=>'product'), array('p.*'))
        ->join(array('m'=>'manufacturers'),'p.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id', array("manufacture_name"=>'m.name'))
        ->join(array('s'=>'category'),'s.category_id = p.category_id', array("sub_category_name"=>'s.name'))
        ->join(array('c'=>'category'),'c.category_id = s.parent', array("category_name"=>'c.name'))
        ->join(array('p_w'=>'prod_warehouse'),'p_w.product_id = p.product_id', array("curent_stock"=>'p_w.curent_stock'))
        ->join(array('r'=>'review'),'p.product_id = r.product_id and r.status = 1', array("avg_review_rating"=>new Zend_Db_Expr('AVG(r.rating)'),"count_user_rating"=>new Zend_Db_Expr('COUNT(r.product_id)')))
        ->limit($limit, $start);

    $list_select->where('s.status = 1 AND c.status = 1 AND p.status = 1 AND m.status = 1 AND p.product_id != "" AND p_w.status > 0');
    $list_select->group('p.product_id');
    $list_select->where('p.featured_product = 1');
    $aData=$oDb->fetchall($list_select);
    return $aData;
}
```

When I execute above, it only fetch product which is having review rate, I also wants to get the product which is not having review rating?

Kindly help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do a LEFT JOIN. Using `$select->joinLeft()`

```
->joinLeft(array('r'=>'review'),'p.product_id = r.product_id and r.status = 1', array("avg_review_rating"=>new Zend_Db_Expr('AVG(r.rating)'),"count_user_rating"=>new Zend_Db_Expr('COUNT(r.product_id)')))
```

The default `join()` method for `Zend_Db_Select` assumes you want to do an `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

protected $_user_profile="user_profile"; // Your table name

protected $_app_functionalities_profile="app_functionalities_profile"; //other table name

$select = $this->select()

->setIntegrityCheck(false)

->from($this->_user_profile)

->from($this->_app_functionalities_profile)

->where('USER_PROFILE.user_id=?',1)

->where('USER_PROFILE.profile_id=app_functionalities_profile.profile_id');

$userdata = $this->fetchAll($select);

Use this for join condition.you can used any other table and where condition for fullfill your requirement.